# how to to pass id to get data flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I am using `getx` rest API by backend URL `id` wise fetch data how to pass `id` to url

`https://localhost.com/api/users/get_planDetail/{id}`

here `id` pass how
this is API URL
`https://localhost.com/api/users/get_planDetail/{id}`

**my plan service**

```dart
    static Future<List?> fetchPlans(int value) async {
    var response = await client.get(
        Uri.parse('https://localhost.com/api/users/get_planDetail/'));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var jsonString = response.body;
      print(jsonString);
      return PlansFromJson(jsonString);
    } else {
      //show error message
      return null;
    }
  }
```

My plan controller

```dart
    var isLoading = true.obs;
  // ignore: deprecated_member_use
  var plansList = <Plans>[].obs;
  RxInt planId = 0.obs;
  @override
  void onInit() {
    fetchPlans();
    super.onInit();
  }

  setPlanId(int id) {
    planId.value = id;
    print(id);
    if (planId.value != 0 && planId.value != null) {
      fetchPlans();
    }
  }

  void fetchPlans() async {
    try {
      isLoading(true);
      var plans = await PlanServices.fetchPlans(planId.value);
      print(plans);
      if (plans != null) {
        plansList.value = plans as List<Plans>;
      }
    } finally {
      isLoading(false);
    }
```

**my `caregories.dart`**

```dart
     onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => PlanDetails(
                                    id: categoryController
                                        .categorysList[index].id)));
                      },
```

**my `plan.dart`**

```dart
     void initState() {
    // call this method for api calling
    planController.setPlanId(widget.id);
    super.initState();
  }
```

I click ontop to id pass my plan services URL like this `https://localhost.com/api/users/get_planDetail/1` how to get data

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass data from previous page like this

```
onTap: () {
    Navigator.push(context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => PlanDetailsScreen(id: 1)));
},
```

This is Your PlanDetailScreen where you need to call controller method

```
class PlanDetailScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final int id;

  const PlanDetailScreen({Key key, this.id}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PlanDetailScreenState createState() => _PlanDetailScreenState();
}

class _PlanDetailScreenState extends State<PlanDetailScreen> {
  PlanController con = Get.put(PlanController());

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // call this method for api calling
    con.setPlanId(widget.id);    
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      // your code
    );
  }
}
```

This your controller file where you need to make function for api calling

```
class PlanController extends GetxController {
  RxInt planId = 0.obs;

  setPlanId(int id) {
    planId.value = id;
    if (planId.value != 0 && planId.value != null) {
      fetchPlans();
    }
  }

  void fetchPlans() async {
    try {
      isLoading(true);
      var plans = await PlanServices.fetchPlans(planId.value);
      if (plans != null) {
        plansList.value = plans as List<Plans>;
      }
    } finally {
      isLoading(false);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you.but  planController.setPlanId(widget.id);
    super.initState(); line widget  Undefined name 'widget'.
Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name.

Comment: The `initState` function should always start by `super.initState();` before any other code. Can you try swapping the two lines inside

Comment: @praveen its working for you?

Comment: i am update code widget.id  widget refer where this line only show error

Comment: And i also update my code stackoverflow

Comment: just add id to your Url

 `Uri.parse('https://localhost.com/api/users/get_planDetail/'+id.toString());`

Comment: @praveen you just need to use id like this https://localhost.com/api/users/get_planDetail/value.toString()

Comment: @RaviLimbani mistake..should be value instead id.

Comment: @praveen if you solved issue please verified it for encourage.

Comment: [GETX] Instance "PlanController" has been created
[GETX] Instance "PlanController" has been initialized
I/flutter ( 6057): null  to  black screen

Comment: @praveen create instance ? like PlanController con = Get.put(PlanController());

Comment: i am create alwats like this   final PlanController planController = Get.put(PlanController());

Comment: planController.setPlanId(widget.id); like error Undefined name 'widget'.
Try correcting the name to one that is defined,

Comment: remove this line void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // call this method for api calling
    con.setPlanId(widget.id);    
  }planId.value = id;
    print(id);  id was null